# Laravel routes conflict

Tags: laravel, routes

I have these two routes:

```
Route::get('doctors/{slug_category}/{slug}', [DoctorController::class, 'detail'])->name('doctor.detail');

Route::get('blog/{slug_category}/{slug}', [PostController::class, 'detail'])->name('post.detail');
```

But I need to remove the prefix like this:

```
Route::get('{slug_category}/{slug}', [DoctorController::class, 'detail'])->name('doctor.detail');

Route::get('{slug_category}/{slug}', [PostController::class, 'detail'])->name('post.detail');
```

Is there a way to do this without having conflicts?

Comment: Without `doctors/` and `blog/`, those are the exact same route. I forget if its the first or second definition that would be used, but either way, one of those is not being used at all. You need to leave them the way they are, or define a shared Controller/Method that handles it properly.

Comment: I'd like to have this routes to have an url with less depth. How I can define a shared Controller/Method? For an idea, Is possible to detect in routes.php which Class is use?

Comment: Remove one of them, and do `Route::get('{slug_category}/{slug}', [ExampleController::class, 'detail'])->name('example.detail');`. Internally in `public function detail()` of `ExampleController`, handle the different possibilities (you'll have to figure that logic out yourself though)

Comment: I'll try it!  thanks